# From an input string to namedtuple python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, input, namedtuple

Hello am a beginner on python and i want to know if ther's away to read a line and transform it to a namedtuple 
i will explain i have this 2 lines

```
MARKS      CLASS      NAME       ID        
92         2          Calum      1
```

For the first line :

```
line = raw_input()
person = namedtuple('person',line)
```

and i made my namedtuple

now while i 'am reading the second line i don't know how to insert those informations in a namedtuple i tried to split it 
i tried all this methods but i coudn't make it

```
>>> line = raw_input().split(' ')
92         2          Calum      1 
>>> line
['92', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', 'Calum', '', '', '', '', '', '1', '']
>>> line = raw_input().split('/t')
92         2          Calum      1 
>>> line
['92         2          Calum      1 ']
>>> line = raw_input().split('        ')
92         2          Calum      1 
>>> line
['92', ' 2', '  Calum      1 ']
>>>
```

Whatever what i am trying i can't have 4 arguments So please if you have any idea how can i split this string into columns help me
thank you 
cordially

Comment: use '\t' instead '/t'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using `split()` will split at any whitespace characters (tabs, or multiple spaces). So

```
line = raw_input()
args = line.split()
```

Then, because namedtuple accepts multiple arguments, not a list, you just have to *unwrap* the argument list, using the `*` operator.

```
person = Person(*args)
```

Comment: input does not work is it removed from python 2.7 or i should use a library ?

Comment: @FEDOUABOUZENOUN: sorry, meant `raw_input`, force of habit

Answer (score 0):

So the answer according to me would be to use '\t' instead of '/t'

```
a=raw_input().split('\t')
```